# How do I get rid of weird pockmarks on the surface of my object?

Tags: mesh, texturing, modifiers

I had been making some icing for a donut when I started to notice these evenly spaced out indentations in the texture of my object. I'm not sure if it's the result of adding a subsurf modifier to my mesh or a bad sculpting job. It looks like the pockmarks are directly related to my mesh though.[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Yeah, of course.